# Laravel 4: Keeping a table Relationship when reducing structure into several tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, relationships

History:

DB: Tables clients and titles

A Client can have many titles but a title can only have one client. So i will use a simple one-to-many relationship as illustrated below:
Client Model

```
  class Client extends Eloquent {
      public function titles(){
          return $this->hasMany('titles');
      }  
  }
```

Then i simply use the following to get the requested data for the selected title

```
  $clientTitles = Client::find(1)->titles;
```

All in all this should list all client associated titles.

My question really comes to this as i am looking to split my data within my titles table into smaller tables as i also use some aspects of the titles data somewhere within the system and do not need to get all of the title details every time.

So i would have another three tables related to the titles data table

**Titles, Title_Artwork, Title_Details, Titles_List**

Now if i use the same as above i will get all the data within the titles table, but not the other three.  So how can i then update my relationship to then scrape the other three title tables so when i need to, i can get all the data, rather.

Or is there another way to do this or NO keep to what i have done an just limit the call to the fields i require?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, And lets assume that your `Titles` model is some what like-

```php
class Titles extends Eloquent{
  public function titleartwork(){
    return ..
  }
  public function titledetails(){
    return ..
  }
  public function titlelist(){
    return ..
  }
}
```

And your client model is-

```php
class Client extends Eloquent {
  public function titles(){
      return $this->hasMany('titles');
  }  
}
```

So in order to get the data of any of these tables `Title_Artwork, Title_Details, Titles_List`
you can do this

```php
$clientTitles = Client::with('Titles','Titles.titleartwork','Titles.titlelist')->where('id','=',1)->get();
```

In terms of Laravel it is known as **Eager Loading**, to know more you can check the [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

It will also work with multiple nesting, I mean if your `Title_Artwork` also contains relationship like-

```php
class TitleArtwork extends Eloquent{
  public function sometable(){
    return ..;
  }
}
```

Then you can get the data of `sometable` using

```php
$clientTitles = Client::with('Titles','Titles.titleartwork.sometable','Titles.titlelist')->where('id','=',1)->get();
```